# Cassandra compaction on few nodes is running slowly

Tags: cassandra

We want cassandra flush to happen less frequently. In the latest version of apache cassandra `memtable_cleanup_threshold` has been deprecated. Is there a way we can still put more data in memtable? We also have `concurrent_compactors` set to 4 and compaction throughput set to 64. but when we run major compaction it still runs only one.

Comment: how slow? can you include schema? are there deletes to that table?

Comment: C* not encountered by storage bottleneck?

Comment: @chris we had a big data migration was going on. Due to continous data flowing in we had to disable autominor compaction during the migration and then kicked off major compaction for that table. It's taking longertime . We have conurrent compactors set to 4 . I just see one compact process running. Can we use parallel compaction for same table? And also memtable is flushing every 3 mb. Is there away to hold may be upto 64mb before it flushes? As memtable_threshold_cleanup is deprecated in latest version how can we reduce memtable flush